# Flutter JSON - How to get Quotes around Variables?

Tags: json, flutter, dart, http-headers

I'm using Flutter to send JSON headers to my NodeJS server.

I need to send an email and a token. But what's wrong with my code?

```
String authuser = '{"email":' + nodemail! + ', "fireToken":' + fireToken+ '}';
```

Instead of the JSON I want which is;

```
 {
  "email":"myemail@myemail.com", 
  "fireToken":"myfiretoken"
 }
```

I'm getting;

```
{
 "email":myemail@gmail.com, 
 "fireToken":myfiretoken
}
```

So how do I send quotes around my email and fireToken variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not try create your own JSON. Intead, use the [`jsonEncode`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.1/dart-convert/jsonEncode.html) from `dart:convert` to convert an object into JSON. In this case we can do it like this:

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  final map = {'email': 'myemail@myemail.com', 'fireToken': 'myfiretoken'};
  final json = jsonEncode(map);
  print(json); // {"email":"myemail@myemail.com","fireToken":"myfiretoken"}
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Flutter does recognize the values as strings without quotes. Add quotes in the speech marks

```
{
  "email":"myemail@myemail.com", // Added quotes in the speech marks
  "fireToken":"myfiretoken" // the same applies here
 }
```